# How to make it possible to set the due date in a approval/feedback workflow to current date?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I created two workflows, one based on the approval workflow and another based on the feedback workflow via SharePoint Designer 2010.
When you start one of the workflows you can set a due date, but at the moment it is not possible to set it to the same date the workflow is created. You have to at least select one day after the date of the workflow creation.

Is it possible to change this behaviour so that it only isn't allowed to select a date in the past but the current date is allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer :) I had to open the initiation form in InfoPath and check the applied rules for the due date field. 
Now I set it to "if due date is less than today()" - only then en error will be desplayed and the current date is valid.
But thank you anyway very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

### In a workflow, it would look like:

> *if* modified* between Current Item:Created and today
>
> *then* do ...

Current Item:Created will pull directly from the field that says when the item was created.

Click the Fx button to get the prompt window you need to select current item:Created.

---

Other possible solution:

You can apply column validation to the column through the LIST SETTINGS within SharePoint.

When the User enters a Date that's before the create date, it can prevent the user from submitting an item.

Here you go. This is a link from SharePointSolutions.com that will walk you through almost exactly what you had described in the above post.

[I am not affiliated with SharePointSolutions.com, but this is the link to the tutorial](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2011/02/how-to-validate-a-due-date-in-a-sharepoint-2010-list/)

*(Kind reminder to upvote and/or choose answers appropriately to actively contribute to StackExchange.)*

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the (second) solution. It sounds good but where do I set this validation? In the task list? I tried that, but it still doesn't work.